# Basic test of OpenMPI + Fortran + C throws different errors depending on strange things

Tags: c, fortran, mpi, openmpi

I'm having strange problems when trying to use OpenMPI together with Fortran and C. This is a Fortran program that calls a C function, and both are using OpenMPI. I've managed to trace the error to this very simple test case:

File `mpi_hello_world.F90`:

```
program mpi_hello_world
  implicit none
  include 'mpif.h'
  integer :: ierror
  call MPI_Init(ierror)
  ! ERROR CHANGES IF I COMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE
  write(*,*) 'before c_function: MPI_COMM_WORLD=',MPI_COMM_WORLD
  call c_function(MPI_COMM_WORLD)
  call MPI_Finalize()
end program mpi_hello_world
```

File `c_function.c`:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void c_function_(MPI_Comm *comm) {
    printf("MPI_Comm comm=%d\n",*comm);
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(commi, &world_rank);
}
```

The output of the program is:

```
before c_function: MPI_COMM_WORLD=           0
MPI_Comm comm=0
```

So it seems like the variable is being passed correctly. After that, I can get two run time errors depending if I comment or not the line that I indicated in the code. If it is like shown (not commented), then I get a Segmentation fault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x2B5330A9A777
#1  0x2B5330A9AD7E
#2  0x2B5331607D3F
#3  0x2B5331350D26
#4  0x4015D2 in c_function_
#5  0x401550 in MAIN__ at mpi_hello_world.F90:?
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 6088 on node pine exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
make: *** [run] Error 139
```

In case I comment that line, I get an error from OpenMPI:

```
[pine:6328] *** An error occurred in MPI_Comm_rank
[pine:6328] *** reported by process [46992071589889,46991237185536]
[pine:6328] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[pine:6328] *** MPI_ERR_COMM: invalid communicator
[pine:6328] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[pine:6328] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

   Process name: [[12732,1],0]
   Exit code:    5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My idea is that there is something wrong with the libraries linking, but I can't figure out what. It would be great if I could tips on how to debug this.

Some more information: I'm using OpenMPI 1.8.4, for compiling both the Fortran and C files. I'm also running with the correct mpirun, as `/path/to/openmpi/1.8.4/common/bin/mpirun -n 1 test`.

To make sure that the correct libraries are being linked, I did:

```
[$]: ldd hello 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffee39d6000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x0007f6a4dca5000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6a4d99f000)
libmpi_mpifh.so.2 => /usr/lib/openmpi/1.8.4/gcc/lib/libmpi_mpifh.so.2 (0x00007f6a4d74a000)
libmpi.so.1 => /usr/lib/openmpi/1.8.4/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.1 (0x00007f6a4d46e000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6a4d0a9000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f6a4ce6c000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f6a4cc56000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6a4ca38000)
libopen-rte.so.7 => /usr/lib/openmpi/1.8.4/gcc/lib/libopen-rte.so.7 (0x00007f6a4c7bb000)
libopen-pal.so.6 => /usr/lib/openmpi/1.8.4/gcc/lib/libopen-pal.so.6 (0x00007f6a4c4cf000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055dacdee9000)
libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007f6a4c2c3000)
libpciaccess.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0 (0x00007f6a4c0ba000)
libcudart.so.6.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.6.0 (0x00007f6a4be69000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6a4bc64000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f6a4ba5c000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f6a4b859000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f6a4b63f000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f6a4b33b000)
```

Any ideas? Anyone with a similar problem?

Comment: You need to use `MPI_Comm_f2c()` to retrieve the C `MPI_Comm` from the `int` value received from Fortran.

Comment: Is there a way to make the calling of C functions from Fortran portable? Fortran does have a MPI_Comm type, but is defined as INTEGER, so I assumed that it was the same in C (as, surprisingly, I could not find in the documentation of OpenMPI an entry for MPI_Comm). Do you know where is MPI_Comm defined, so I can see if it makes sense to cast is as an int?

Comment: See chap 17.2.4 of the current MPI standard

Comment: And look at the `ISO_C_BINDING` module for portably inter-operate between C and Fortran

Comment: Yes, that seemed to be it. Thank you a lot! And the reference to the standard was perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of MPI_Comm is in `mpi.h` but it is different in different MPI implementations, some use a pointer, some use an int.

You have to use the conversion routines @Giles mentioned in the first comment. Be also aware they may be just macros and not functions. By far it is easier to pass the Fortran integer to C and convert it there (notice `MPI_Fint` instead of `int` to be sure).

```
void c_function_(MPI_Fint *fcomm) {
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_Comm_f2c(fcomm), &world_rank);
}
```

If you need to call the conversion from Fortran, it is more complicated. The main complication is the possibility that it is a macro.
I personally use this (https://github.com/LadaF/PoisFFT/blob/master/src/f_mpi_comm_c2f.c):

```
#include <mpi.h>

// This function is callable from Fortran. MPI_Comm_c2f itself may be just a macro.
MPI_Fint f_MPI_Comm_c2f(MPI_Comm *comm) {
  return MPI_Comm_c2f(*comm);
}
```

and in Fortran

```
  interface
    ! Intentionally returning integer and not integer(c_int).
    ! `c_handle` is a pointer to a C comm, not a C comm itself!
    ! We cannot be sure what Fortran type a C comm is!
    integer function MPI_Comm_c2f(c_handle) bind(C, name="f_MPI_Comm_c2f")
      use iso_c_binding
      type(c_ptr), value :: c_handle
    end function
  end interface
```